# How do I intercept XHR requests in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I need to switch from UIWebView to WKWebView in an iOS project.

I need to intercept all XmlHttpRequests. That was easy with UIWebView but it doesn't seem to be that easy with WKWebView.

I've implemented the navigationDelegate and the `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` but it is not called for XHRs.

Is there any way to intercept them with WKWebView?